# type "name" = Int - is it worth declaring?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, declaration

I have a function that returns the Price of a product, it currently looks like

```
priceOfProduct:: Int -> Int -> Int
```

Is it worth declaring

```
type Price = Int
```

so that the function becomes

```
priceOfProduct :: Int -> Int -> Price ?
```

I thought of doing this, as I then go on to use tuples of Ints, which would maybe look better if they were their own data structure.

```
priceVsTaxed -> Price -> Int -> (Price, Price)
```

Is this useful? Is this necessary?

Is this good Haskell style?

Is declaring a data structure that looks more like renaming an existing Data Structure good style?

Comment: `Int -> Int -> Price` isn't that helpful, because the name of the function already strongly implies a price is returned. `type Quantity = Int` and `type UnitPrice = Int` would allow the much more helpful `priceOfProduct :: Quantity -> UnitPrice -> Price`, though.

Comment: It is also an easy way to alter the type in case you are not very certain whether it will fit in the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not always worth defining extra types, but definitely avoid `Int -> ... -> Int` signatures. These make it very hard to understand how a function is supposed to be used.

So in fact I'd say you should probably rename not only the result but in particular also the arguments. Then, if somebody wants to use your function, they can just let the compiler explain the arguments:

```
foo :: Price
foo = priceOfProduct _ _ + priceOfProduct _ _
```

will give a compiler (GHC>=7.10) message like

```
Foo.hs:Y:X: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: PriceOfProductFirstArgument
    • In the first argument of ‘priceOfProduct’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: priceOfProduct _ _
      In an equation for ‘foo’: main = foo = priceOfProduct _ _ + priceOfProduct _ _
```

You should however consider if you don't want to make the type distinction more rigid: a simple `type`def can never save you from putting the arguments in wrong order, so perhaps you'd better make it

```
newtype Price = Price {priceInEuroCents :: Int}
```

That also avoids ambiguity as to what currency / quantity the price is given in.

Comment: Small addition to the last `newtype`: `newtype Price u = Price { getPrice :: Int }` with `data Euro`, `data USDollar`, … makes it possible to re-use `Price` functions with different currencies.

Comment: @Zeta that's probably the right thing for real-world financial applications (because currency exchange isn't quite an isomorphism), but I don't generally like this approach for quantities-with-units. Such a data type should IMO abstract over the general physical notion of that quantity, without any reference to a concrete unit system.